# How to validate Google Developer console

Tags: api, google-app-engine

Is there any way to validate [Google Developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/) ?

> I want to validate the "CLIENT ID" and "CLIENT SECRET" is valid and
> that is enabled the required APIs

In my application the client can enter their own App, that's why i need validation

All thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: can you elaborate?  usually you use id and secret to enable APIs, and I don't know of any API for the developer console....  If you want to validate the secret is valid... just use an API and you'll see what happens... if it's not valid, it'll bounce the API call.

Comment: @Julldar Question updated as why i need that validation